# update sql query where select max

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a query that updates the max number of the id... here is my code..

```
UPDATE `jobs` SET `sectors` = '12' WHERE `id` = (SELECT MAX(`id`) FROM `jobs`)
```

the error says : `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'wpjb_job' for update in FROM clause`

what can I do to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `id` is a unique field then you can use the query below:

```
UPDATE `jobs` 
SET `sectors` = '12' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

If it is not unique then you need to use a temporary table:

```
UPDATE `jobs`
SET `sectors` = '12'
WHERE `id` = (SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM `jobs`) as temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

as  AVD says use table alias like this

```
  UPDATE jobs
    SET sectors= '12'
    WHERE ID = (select * from (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM jobs) as t)
```